# File name matching with fnmatch

Tags: python

I have a directory with files with the format: `LnLnnnnLnnn.txt`

where L = letters and n = numbers. E.g: `p2c0789c001.txt`

I would like to separate these files based on whether the second number (i.e. 0789) is within a certain sequence of numbers (e.g. 0001 to 0146).

Is there an easy way to do this with fnmatch? Or should I be using regex?

This is the code I have so far:

```
out_files = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
   for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '???[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]????*.txt'):
       out_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: is it always between letters like `c and c` in your example?

Comment: Yes, the letters do not change. It's only the numbers that change in a sequencial order.

Comment: `(r"c([0-9_]+)c", s)` will find the numbers between the c's using re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it easily inside `fnmatch.filter()`, but you could do it yourself:

```
out_files = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
   for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '???[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]????*.txt'):
       if(1 <= int(filename[3:7]) <= 146):
           out_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Or, for the list-comprehension fans:

```
import os
import fnmatch
out_files = [os.path.join(root, filename)
             for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.')
             for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames,
                                            '???[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]????*.txt')
             if 1 <= int(filename[3:7]) <= 146]
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Whoops, forgot an extra for loop. Also, see if this has better performance.

**EDIT2**: Just in case the first letter is a `c`, checks the second to last element, which based on the criteria for both alternatives is guaranteed to exist.

```
out_files = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filesnames:
        try:
            if  1 <= int(filename.split('c')[-2]) <= 146:
                out_files.append(...)
        except IndexError:
            continue
```

---

Alternatively, using a generator:

```
out_files = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in (name for name in filenames if 'c' in name):
        if  1 <= int(filename.split('c')[-2]) <= 146:
            out_files.append(...)
```

Comment: You mean the `if 1 <=...` line? Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In case there are other `c's`at the start of the string or the string length before the numbers  changes:

`if 1 <= int(re.findall(r"c([0-9]+)c", s)[0]) <= 487`:

Or if there are always four digits:

```
if 1 <= int(re.findall(r"c(\d{4})c", s)[0]) <= 487:
```